# iOS WKWebview UserAgent is being set on iPhone but not for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

When I open or launch the site on iPhone in wkwebview it gets the application "userAgent" in the request Header automatically but in the same scenario it is not happening for iPad.

Creation of the WKWebview below:

let wkWebView = WKWebView()

Answer (score 0):

You can create `WKWebViewConfiguration` and pass it with `WKWebView` creation.

```
// Create custom configuration object.
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Add your user agent here."

// Create WebView object with your configuration object.
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
```

This way it will work for all your devices.

Comment: Any idea why it is working for iPhone with let wkWebView = WKWebView() but not for iPad?

Comment: I can't give you concert answer without looking at code.